# React lifecycle methods not trigger, is there some hack behind lifecycle methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, react-native, react-lifecycle

Today I found something like which I was not expected. This does not happen in Angular or maybe another JS library/framework. But today I was shocked when React lifecycle methods not triggered. Is there some hack behind it. let's see the code.

I have a component **A**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class A extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('component mount', this.props.name);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        Hello - {this.props.name}
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default A;
```

I initialized that component twice in **App** component with some conditions:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import A from './A';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isShow: true
    };

    this.setIsShow = this.setIsShow.bind(this);
  }

  setIsShow() {
    this.setState(() => {
      return {isShow: !this.state.isShow};
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.setIsShow}>Show A1</button>
        <button onClick={this.setIsShow}>Show A2</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        {this.state.isShow ? <A name="A1" /> 
        :
        <A name="A2" />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Now, what is expected behavior? **name** props value changed when I clicked on buttons. that's expected, alright. But there is no lifecycle method called when component reinitialized :(. The **componentDidMount** fire only once.

> Now add **key** property in **A** component selector and you will see **componentDidMount** called on every time whenever **A** component reinitialized.

```
{
 this.state.isShow ? <A name="A1" key="1" /> 
 :
 <A name="A2" key="2" />
}
```

This is the expected behavior. But the question is why not without **key** property.

Checkout Online demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/problem-react-lifecycle

Comment: Use `getDerivedStateFromProps` method to get revised props

Comment: Question is not like how to resolve this thing, the question is its breaks the component definition and it's lifecycle :)

Comment: except it doesn't break the lifecycle because its just not unmounting and remounting the component.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is react is optimizing the rendering for you. The same component is rendered with an updated prop vs unmounting and remounting with a different prop.

The lifecycle events are running just fine, you are just not seeing your `console.log` because `componentDidMount` is only fired on mount. If you use another lifecycle event like `componentDidUpdate` you will notice it fires on each change.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  console.log("component update", this.props.name);
}
```

[See a live example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-sunset-9xr8k)

When you don't specify a key react will add one internally... if the component is the same then the same key would be generated for that component meaning it wont be unmounted. There is no need to undergo the extra overhead of unmounting and remounting essentially.

However, specifying a different key for the component forces the unmount and remount because to react you've told it that these should be treated as completely different components

Answer (score -1):

**Edited:**
This is because React is optimizing to not rerender the entire component. Adding another lifecycle method will show the expected output in the console

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  console.log('component update', this.props.name);
}
```

Comment: Where are multiple state updates occurring, to be batched processed? Tested with `this.setState(prevState => ({isShow: !prevState.isShow}));` and still repros.

Comment: @John Ruddell is correct, just try adding componentDidUpdate to your A.js file and you will see.